# How to give a docker image some arguments in the Dockerfile?

Tags: ruby, docker

Is there something like:

`FROM ruby RUBY_MAJOR=2.1 RUBY_VERSION=2.1.5`

I know that I could write ruby:2.1.5, but this is just an example for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You only have the tags defined by the creator. This might change in future versions of Docker.